# Parsing a String to Date

Tags: java, string, date, simpledateformat

String that I want to parse:

> Sun Nov 10 10:00:00 CET 2013

My code:

```
substrings = "Sun Nov 10 10:00:00 CET 2013"

SimpleDateFormat parserSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy");
Date date = parserSDF.parse(substrings);
```

Compiler error output:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sun Nov 10 10:00:00 CET 2013"
>     at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
>     ...

Comment: I believe you mean to use lower-case z's and have 2 d's.

Comment: Also, don't use substrings[0] seeing as substrings is not an array.

Comment: is `substrings` a String or a String[] ?

Comment: My bad, I was adapting from a complex code, editing...

Comment: take a look at this one...http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/SimpleDateFormat.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are missing the correct Locale. Try this, in your example:

```
    SimpleDateFormat parserSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy", Locale.US);
```

Comment: That Locale.US was the annoyance...

Comment: i got no different output with `Locale.US`:  Sun Nov 10 04:00:00 EST 2013

Comment: @foampile Probably your default Locale already is Locale.US. Are you getting the same ParseException that Facon had?

Answer (score 0):

ZZZ will attempt to format the time zone in accordance to RFC 822 time zone, use zzz instead.

[Here's the JavaDoc link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for reference

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes.

```
String input = "Sun Nov 10 10:00:00 CET 2013";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z uuuu" , Locale.US );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

> zdt.toString(): 2013-11-10T10:00+01:00[Europe/Paris]

The terrible old `java.util.Date` class was replaced years ago by the `java.time.Instant` class. Both represent a moment in UTC. To adjust from the time zone seen above to UTC, simply extract a `Instant` object.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;  // Adjust from time zone to UTC.
```

Avoid [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html). But if you must interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, you can convert back and forth. See the new methods added to the old classes, such as [`Date.from`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#from(java.time.Instant)) and [`Date::toInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toInstant()) methods.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that parserSDF takes a string rather than an array and a ParsePosition. I wrote this to output what I think you want.

```
import java.text.*;
public class Parser{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    String input = "Sun Nov 10 10:00:00 CET 2013";
    SimpleDateFormat parserSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy");
    System.out.println(parserSDF.parse(input, new ParsePosition(0)));
    }
}
```

I recommend taking a look at [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) and [ParsePosition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/ParsePosition.html) within the API